# Front wheel Fork is having scratches and Oil is getting leaked from it?

Tags: fork, suspension

I thought that it might be a fault of Oil seal but Mechanic was telling that I have to replace both the fork If I replace only the Oil & Oil seal then again It will leak oil.

Is it a dangerous problem and should I replace both the forks?

Below is an image found on this blog
http://thegoldenwrench.blogspot.in/2012/04/same-sad-story.html

Thanks. 
[image: fork found on the internet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That stanchion is stuffed and needs to be replaced.  If the damage is from normal wear and tear the other will need replacement - probably cheaper to get a whole new fork. If its accident damage (e.g from rubbing while on a car rack) and the other is in very good condition, replacing the damaged one is an option (if you can find a single replacement).

Replacing the oil will buy you a couple of rides and a mess to clean up at the end of each one, and the shock will not perform particularly well.

Its not really a dangerous problem, but the fork will not be working properly and will sag under load.

Comment: This is the correct answer, however, fork oil is cheap and if you're handy you could eek out some  more life from your fork if you're willing to learn how to rebuild it yourself. Takes less than an hour to pull apart and give a good clean and reassemble once you know your way about. I've a Fox Float with knackered seals that I rebuild periodically to keep it running, finding replacements has been trying.
PS This is an option as opposed to binning the whole thing, if you can do a proper repair that would be the best option, of course.

Comment: @alex,Thanx Decent suggession Mr. Alex will sure try that.